# What is $|T|$ when $|R| = 30,\;R\cup T = 45,\;R\cap T = 8\;?$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> If $|R| = 30$ and $R\cup T = 45$, and $R\cap T = 8,\,$ is $\,|T| = 15$?

Do you just ignore the value of the intersection?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Generally, for all finite sets $X$ and $Y$,
$$\lvert X\cup Y\rvert = \lvert X\rvert + \lvert Y\rvert - \lvert X\cap Y\rvert \text. $$
Intuitively, this means: You simply add the cardinalities, but doing this, you counted the elements that are in both sets twice, therefore you need to subtract the cardinality of the intersection (which is just the number of elements that are in both sets).

In this example, this implies
$$\lvert T\rvert=\lvert R\cup T\rvert-\lvert R\rvert+\lvert R\cap T\rvert = 45-30+8=23 \text.$$

Answer (score 2):

Not quite. For example the sets $R\cup T=\{1,\cdots,30\}\cup\{1,\cdots,45\}=\{1,\cdots,45\}$ has exactly 45 elements, but T in this case has size 45. You really need the value of the intersection. Try drawing a Venn Diagram, or maybe a few more examples.

You really need $|A\cap B|+|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|$, which again you can convince yourself is true using a Venn Diagram maybe!